# Why is GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName an "undeclared identifier"

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center, gamekit

Countless GameCenter tutorials do this:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(localUserAuthenticationChanged) name:GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName object:nil];
```

I have other standard GameCenter methods for authenticating users, etc, but I wanted to received notifications of game center login changes while app is in background; according to a lot of books, online tips, the above code line is how you listen.

But I cannot build the app. It claims `name:GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName` is an undeclared identifier... this, right after other GameCenter code works fine (and the libraries and frameworks are indeed imported).

Any idea what is wrong with my `name:GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import game kit in the file where you have that code.

Comment: whoops, i thought i had, but i put it in a different file by mistake! thanks.